# Not updated in webpage, when text file is updated

Tags: jquery

Tried this to read a local text file in a html page using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

       <script charset="utf-8" src = "jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
function read()
{
    $.get("version.txt", function(data) {
     document.write(data);
});

setTimeout(read, 2000);

}
</script>

<body onload="read()">

How r u
</body>
</html>
```

Its working, but when the text file is updated the changes are not being reflected in the page. could someone help me with this?

Comment: Most likely caching (and rightly so). Try appending a unique querystring on the end of the url to test: `$.get("version.txt?_ts=" + new Date().getTime())`

Comment: pls remove document.write(data); replace width $('body').text(data);

Comment: Thanks Mr. RGraham its working. Thankyou very much